# Download many files async from Http

Tags: c#, http, asynchronous

I have a http server and I need to download files from that server to my computer every time I launch the app on my PC, I need to download about five thousand files and each of them are about 1-2 kb. Here is the code that I use for it:

```
WebClient[][] wbc = new WebClient[1][];

for(int file=0 ; file < myfilecount ; file++)
{
    wbc[0][film] = new WebClient();
    wbc[0][film].Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
    wbc[0][film].DownloadFileCompleted += Form4_DownloadFileCompleted;
    wbc[0][film].DownloadFileTaskAsync("http://MYIPADDRESS/File" + file.ToString(), databaselocation + "\\File" + file.toString());
}
```

When I do this it downloads files into ram in about 3 sec. But it takes about one minute to write them to my hdd. Is there any faster way to download those files to my HDD?

Also I am getting the information about the count of those files by a file that I write, so is there any better way to download all of them?

Comment: `DownloadFileTaskAsync` returns a Task. You need to wait that task. Otherwise, don't use the async method.

Comment: `every time i launch the app in my pc, i need to download about five thousand files` I think you might remake your flow, cause downloading thousands of files each time the app starts is bad

Comment: "but it takes about one minute to write them to my hdd. Is there any faster way to download those files to my hdd?" I/O is **always** going to give you a performance hit.  You could get an SSD or a faster HD, but that's about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree if this is required **every time you launch the app on your pc** you should rethink the process.  But then again, I don't completely know your circumstances.  That aside, you can make a queued collection of request tasks and wait for them all concurrently:

```
var requestTasks = Enumerable.Range(0, myFileCount).Select(i => {
  var webClient = new WebClient
  {
     Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password),
     DownloadFileCompleted += Form4_DownloadFileCompleted
  };  

  return webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync("http://MYIPADDRESS/File" + i.ToString(), Path.Combine(databaselocation, "file" + i.ToString()));
});

await Task.WhenAll(requestTasks);
```

Also I believe WebClient is limited to the number of requests that can be made concurrently to the same host, you can configure this by using [ServicePointManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = carefullyCalculatedNumber;
```

I'd be careful with the number of connections allowed, too high of a limit can also become a problem. Hope this helps.

Comment: _"you can make a queued collection of request tasks and wait for them all concurrently"_ -- and that will improve the time it takes to write the data to disk...how, exactly?

Comment: After re-reading it looks like he is running an HDD which at that point parallel won't do a thing.  You are correct it won't do anything, His best bet at that point would be to do them sequentially one by one to avoid beating up his HDD @PeterDuniho.

Comment: So, do you really believe your post in any way is an answer to the _question_ the OP asked?

Comment: I still think it does hold value for those trying to optimize in the event he does run on a different disk and IO is not the limitation.  But I can remove this answer if you feel so strongly. :-)

Comment: I tried it just in case but unfortunately it didn't work. Accoridng to your answers is that better to zip the files in the server and unzip them in my pc again?